# using method in meteor collection

Tags: mongodb, methods, meteor

I try to use a collection of objects which has some methods.

ie :

```
Targets = new Meteor.Collection("targets");
Targets.insert({
  id : 0,
  title : function(){
    if(false){
      console.log("true");
      return 'Le commencement';
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("false");
      return 'Le début';
    }
  },
  text : 'Lorem ipsum dolor.',
});`
```

I call the title later with

```
Template.content.target = function() {
  var currentPosition = Meteor.user().profile.position;
  return Targets.findOne({id: parseInt(currentPosition)});
};
```

and in my template :

```
{{#if currentUser}}
  <h2>{{target.title}}</h2>
  <p>{{target.text}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

The Meteor reaction is completely random...

Sometimes i get the "false" in my console and the title is "Le début". 
Sometimes i get "Le commencement" as the title and nothing in the console. 
Sometimes i get the "false" twice in the console and "Le début" as a title for a few seconds then it disepears...

I dunno what to do ...

Maybe just method in objects stored in mongo is a very bad ideas.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongodb is a database, you should't put some logic code inside. So you need to extract the attributes of your object and then use a [transform function](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection) in your collection. Like this:

```
Targets = new Meteor.Collection("targets", {
    transform: function(doc) {
        return new Target(doc)
    }
});
```

Or if you don't want to create a `Target` object:

```
Targets = new Meteor.Collection("targets", {
    transform: function(doc) {
        doc.title = function(){
            if(false) {
                console.log("true");
                return 'Le commencement';
            } else {
                console.log("false");
                return 'Le début';
            }
        return doc
        }
    }
});
```